# W3C Font-Family Parse error 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

Tags: css, fonts

Why do I get an Parse error ( line 24 ) on this line of CSS?

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

the full Code where I get this error is:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  /* IE7 inline-block hack */
  *zoom: 1;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #212121;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    font: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    min-height: 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 33px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In a CSS file you should use double quotes `"`...

Comment: **Where** do you get a parse error (i.e. in what tool)?

Comment: What is the context this code is in? Parse errors are often caused by a problem on the previous line. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto — Nonsense. [Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings)

Comment: @Quentin I use the W3C validator.

Comment: If you remove the 2 asterisks `*` from the beginning of the 3rd and 5th lines, then you get no errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`property: value` pairs must go inside a ruleset.

> ```
> font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
> ```

… is not a valid stylesheet.

```
foo {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

… is.

---

Re edit:

The errors you are seeing are a side effect of the IE7 hacks at the beginning of the ruleset.

Remove the IE7 hacks. The browser is a decade out of date and doesn't even get security updates now.